# What is UWP equivalent of Xaml data format field in DataFormats class of WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've been trying to find out a UWP equivalent of [DataFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataformats?view=netframework-4.7.2) Class in WPF that has `Xaml` as a data format field - or may be there is a workaround in UWP?

As shown in the link above, the `Xaml` is one of the data format in WPF's `DataFormats` class. But so far I've not found such an equivalent in UWP. The [StandardDataFormats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats) Class in UWP does not list `Xaml` as one of its Data Format.

**Motivation**:

Similar to the `WPF` example shown here: [TextRange.Save method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textrange.save?view=netframework-4.7.2), I'm trying convert the following `WPF` code to a `UWP` code. But as you can see on line `range.Save(outputStream, DataFormats.Xaml);` the WPF code is using `Xaml` as data format when saving the range selection to a memory stream:

```
....
var doc = new FlowDocument();
var range = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   range.Save(outputStream, DataFormats.Xaml);
   outputStream.Position = 0;
   using (var xamlStream = new StreamReader(outputStream))
   {
      var xaml = xamlStream.ReadToEnd();
      File.WriteAllText(xamlFileName, xaml);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UWP's `TextRange` struct does not have a method named `Save` so your question is moot.

To my knowledge, UWP does not (easily) support manipulating XAML markup at runtime (e.g. there is no `XamlWriter` class, and there is no API for the manipulating of XAML, though `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader` and `XmlBinaryWriter` are available, they don't seem intended for use by application developers, but are meant for the build process).

If you want to serialize a UWP `TextRange` in a way that maintains document structure I think you'll need to serialize (and deserialize) that yourself using some custom logic (though I wonder what happens if you pass your `TextRange` instance into `JsonConvert.SerializeObject( ... )`...).